# How to implement if statements in try catch

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm currently trying to implement an if statement inside a try/catch.

The code I have is as following:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/config.php");
require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/functions.php");
startSession();
define('DSN','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=solvedesktop');
define('USERNAME' , 'root');
define('PASSWORD' , '');

try {
    $DB = new PDO(DSN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM drop_down WHERE published = 1 AND loggedin = 1";
        $result = $DB->query($sql);
        $row_count = $result->rowCount();
        if($row_count){
            $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM drop_down WHERE published = 1 AND loggedin = 0";
        $result = $DB->query($sql);
        $row_count = $result->rowCount();
        if($row_count){
            $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

In the body looks like the following:

```
<?php
    $items = $rows;
    $id = '';
    echo "<ul class ='multidrop'>";
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent_id'] == 0){
            echo "<li><a href=../home/view.php?id=".$item['id'].">".$item['title']."</a>";
            $id = $item['id'];
            sub($items, $id);
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    function sub($items, $id){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($items as $item){
            if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
                echo "<li><a href=../home/view.php?id=".$item['id'].">".$item['title']."</a>";
                sub($items, $item['id']);
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

At first I had a simple try/catch where the page only had to be published to be readable on the front end, however I have since decided that some pages need to be protected for users only, therefore I needed to implement the if statement inside the try/catch, I don't believe I'm too far away (provided it can be done) however I'm struggling to finish off this part of my website.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  You have a missing curly bracket on the second catch.  FWIW, this is a case where it would be good to encapsulate your database calls so that you don’t repeat yourself. Notice how much code you’re typing again?  It belongs in a function, or better yet, in a class. Your try/catch could extend over your logic and present a different view if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @TimMorton, the error message I'm getting is: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\dynnav.php on line 31.

Ya I was thinking about doing it in function form alright, I don't really understand try/catch so trying to figure it out. I agree I've a lot of duplicate info there alright.

Also where is the missing bracket?
I think I must be looking at this too long and I just can't see it :)

Comment: Just spotted it, had the bracket in the wrong spot. @TimMorton thanks for pointing that out, this is working for me now :)

Comment: Glad to help :)